# Change a generic object's type at runtime?

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting

I have a generic class called `ResizingArray` whose purpose is self-evident.

So I can do something like this:

`ResizingArray<ClassA> array = new ResizingArray<ClassA>();`

I'd like to be able to take that existing instance and then do this:

`array = new ResizingArray<ClassB>();`

Is this possible and if-so, how can it be done? The reason why I'd like it to be the same object is for memory-related reasons that I will not get in to.

Comment: You could declare it as `object array` or `dynamic array`

Comment: Oh forgot about object! Stupid question in hindsight. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a Liskov Substitution problem in the making...

Comment: No trust me I loooooooove generics.. so much to the point where I completely forgot object exists since it's never in my code. I actually had a solution involving unsafe pointers working because I thought of that before object.. lol

Comment: Assuming that `ResizingArray<T>` is a `class` and not a `struct`, remember that assigning a different value to the variable does _not_ replace the memory that was used.  If nothing else references the original array then the GC will release the memory _when it needs to_.  So your apparent "memory needs" may not be solved by just replacing the variable value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are talking about objects and not structs you are only talking about reusing the pointer, and not the memory used by the actual objects. So there is no appreciable memory benefit. Classic case of premature optimization if you ask me.

Just make a new variable, And keep the scope of the variables as local as possible. Trust me you won't see a difference. Otherwise, the only way to do so would be to revert to object, but losing the maintainability is absolutely not worth the few bytes you would save.